# vim-bookmark cannot display correct symbol in gvim (Windows)

Tags: vim

I have installed [this plugin](https://github.com/MattesGroeger/vim-bookmarks) for metter bookmark management. It actually does work but I am having problems with the used symbols.

The installation says to check `:echo has('signs')` to work correctly. If it returns 1, which it does for me, it is working correctly.

`:set encdoing` is set to `latin1` and I am getting the error `E239: Invalid sign text: <something>`.

I believe that this is an encoding issue. I have also tryed ut8, but the same problem occures.

```
call s:set('g:bookmark_sign',                '⚑')
call s:set('g:bookmark_annotation_sign',     '☰')
```

This is what the symbols should look like. The font I am using is Consolas.

Comment: Why don't you try [the issue tracker](https://github.com/MattesGroeger/vim-bookmarks/issues)?

Comment: There is a user who posted the same issue 19 days ago. Until now there was noe response from nobody.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue has already being posted on the issue tracker and it bothers you so much that you don't want to wait for the solution, then you should try and fix the problem yourself and open a pull request.

I doubt anyone on SO is going to the trouble of understanding that plugin, setting-up an environment to reproduce the problem and investigate it further.

As the plugins probably works for most of its users, you could first check if the problem is related to some plugin or setting that you are using. To do this you could follow the procedure described on [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5). Some relevant parts follows:

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual
>   runtime files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it
>   is a simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc
>   or .gvimrc. So first, start vim like this:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> this starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.
>
> If the error does not occur when starting Vim this way, then the
>   problem is either related to some plugin of yours or some setting in
>   one of your local setup files. You need to find out, what triggers the
>   error, you try starting Vim this way:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
> ```
>
> If the error occurs, the problem is your .viminfo file. Simply delete
>   the viminfo file then. If the error does not occur, try:
>
> ```
> vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load
>   any plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly
>   caused by some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending
>   on the length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the
>   origin within that file.
>
> The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
>   Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
>   occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half
>   of your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be
>   in the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
>   middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and
>   move your way along, until you find the problematic option. If your
>   .vimrc is 350 lines long, you need at a maximum 9 tries to find the
>   offending line (in practise, this can often be further reduced, since
>   often lines depend on each other).
>
> If the problem does not occur, when only loading your .vimrc file, the
>   error must be caused by a plugin or another runtime file (indent
>   autoload or syntax script). Check the output of the :scriptnames
>   command to see what files have been loaded and for each one try to
>   disable each one by one and see which one triggers the bug. Often
>   files that are loaded by vim, have a simple configuration variable to
>   disable them, but you need to check inside each file separately.

Obviously you will have to adapt the procedure to always have the bookmark plugin loaded; you can use `:scriptnames` to ensure that it is actually loaded (you should probably retain your plugin manager, if you are using one).

If the bookmark plugin is the only one loaded and you have no custom settings and it still doesn't work them you probably have a problem with your Vim/gVim installation.